# Como atribuir valores a variáveis através de CheckBoxes e a partir daí criar TextViews específicas em uma outra activity

Tags: android, checkbox, textview

Galera, eu gostaria que fossem atribuídos valores a uma variável de acordo com a seleção de uma determinada CheckBox no meu projeto.

Em um exemplo. Se a primeira checkbox fosse selecionada, fosse atribuído a variável cont o seguinte: `cont+=1.`

Se a segunda checkbox fosse selecionada, fosse atribuído a variável cont o seguinte: `cont+=2`.

Com isso na outra activity fosse apresentada uma condição baseado no valor da variável cont.

`se cont==1` então fosse criada uma textview aparecendo um determinado texto e `se cont==2` aparecesse uma outra textview com outro texto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora eu também gostaria que se selecionada uma segunda checkbox (uma das duas na parte mais abaixo, "empregado" ou "desempregado"), na activity seguinte fosse criada uma outra textview aparecendo o seguinte conteúdo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que não me serve uma única textview com os 2 textos unidos (em sequência).

Códigos:

**MainActivity.java**

```js
package genesysgeneration.stack;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    public int cont=0;
    private Button btnNext;
    private CheckBox cbCasado, cbSolteiro, cbEmpregado, cbDesempregado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        Intent it = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(it);

    }

}
```

**Main2Activity.java**

```js
package genesysgeneration.stack;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }
}
```

**Desde já agradecido!!!**

Comment: Se você sabe de antemão a quantidade máxima e mínima de textViews que vai usar na segunda activity, então crie-os e só adicione algum valor a eles quando necessário. Caso não soubesse quantos textViews iria usar, teria que usar uma listView customizada que só receberia textViews.

Comment: No caso de usando a dica do @Mr_Anderson, se fizer isso, basta que voce passe os status dos checkbox para a outra ativity e logicamente se tiver checado voce atribui os valores dos textos para os textviews correspondentes a cada um que tiver checado ou não

Comment: Eu consegui utilizando uma textview como referência, printava nela para poder passar para a proxima activity usando "it.putExtra(..."

De qualquer forma, muito OBRIGADO!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mais uma que eu descobri a resposta pouco depois que fiz a pergunta, mas mesmo passado esse tempo todo ninguém respondeu.

Segue a solução que encontrei e julguei ser a melhor para o meu problema:

Main1.java:

```js
package genesysgeneration.stack;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button btnNext;
    private CheckBox cbCasado, cbSolteiro, cbEmpregado, cbDesempregado;
    private String estadoCivil, estadoEmprego;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cbCasado=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbCasado);
        cbSolteiro=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbSolteiro);
        cbEmpregado=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbEmpregado);
        cbDesempregado=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbDesempregado);

        addCB();

        btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void addCB(){

        cbCasado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (cbSolteiro.isChecked()){

                    cbSolteiro.setChecked(false);
                    estadoCivil="";

                }

                if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){

                    estadoCivil="Casado";

                }else {

                    estadoCivil="";

                }

            }
        });

        cbSolteiro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (cbCasado.isChecked()){

                    cbCasado.setChecked(false);
                    estadoCivil="";

                }

                if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){

                    estadoCivil="Solteiro";

                }else {

                    estadoCivil="";

                }

            }
        });

        cbEmpregado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (cbDesempregado.isChecked()){

                    cbDesempregado.setChecked(false);
                    estadoEmprego="";

                }

                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){

                    estadoEmprego="Empregado";

                }else {

                    estadoEmprego="";

                }

            }
        });

        cbDesempregado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (cbEmpregado.isChecked()){

                    cbEmpregado.setChecked(false);
                    estadoEmprego="";

                }

                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){

                    estadoEmprego="Desempregado";

                }else {

                    estadoEmprego="";

                }

            }
        });

    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        Intent it = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        it.putExtra("estadoCivil", estadoCivil);
        it.putExtra("estadoEmprego", estadoEmprego);
        startActivity(it);

    }

}
```

Coloquei uma condição para que o usuário não possa selecionar ao mesmo tempo casado e solteiro/ empregado e desempregado... Que ao selecionar a segunda checkbox, se a outra oposta estiver selecionada, seja desmarcada:

```js
if (cbSolteiro.isChecked()){

    cbSolteiro.setChecked(false);
    estadoCivil="";

}
```

Main2.java:

```js
package genesysgeneration.stack;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tv01, tv02;
    private String estadoCivil, estadoEmprego;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        tv01=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv01);
        tv02=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv02);

        estadoCivil=getIntent().getStringExtra("estadoCivil");
        estadoEmprego=getIntent().getStringExtra("estadoEmprego");

        tv01.setText(String.valueOf("O sujeito é " + estadoCivil + "."));
        tv02.setText(String.valueOf("O sujeito é " + estadoEmprego + "."));

    }
}
```

Tem de importar as duas strings exportadas da activity anterior e pedir para os TextViews as exibirem...